# how to solve the following double integral with infinite limits?

Tags: integration

Evaluate the following double integral with infinite limits.

may be some completing the square works

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ $e^{(2x^2+2xy+2y^2)}dx dy$

i have no idea how to proceed further? i think some substitution is required but don't know which one?

Comment: you sure there isn't a minus sign before your paranthesis?

Comment: I also think that it should be $\int\int e^{-(2x^2+2xy+2y^2)}dx dy$

Comment: no everything is correct

Answer (score 1):

The quadratic form $x^2+xy+y^2$ is positive definite, and its matrix has eigenvalues $1/2$ and $3/2$. So you can find coordinates $u,v$ obtained from $x,y$ using an orthogonal matrix such that
$$
2x^2+2xy+2y^2=u^2+3v^2.
$$

Comment: @ Jonas great..